# Magento site not working after changing location

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento site. When I changed it location, it is not working.

**I am getting the errors :**

`The page isn't redirecting properly` in Mozilla.

`This webpage has a redirect loop` in Chrome.

For changing the location what I have done is:

1) Imported my database and changed the urls in `core_config_data` table.

2) Changed the db credentials in local.xml

3) Cleared the var folder.

I have found various solutions for the same problem but nothing resolved my issue.

```
Like clearing the cache, auto increment of ids in database etc.
```

**I am able to access my backend**

Comment: Have a look at the .htaccess file and look for improper redirects.

Comment: try to clear your chrome cache...chrome does weird things sometimes...

Comment: Check also if you don't have hard-coded base urls in app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I go through when I find such problems

Delete the cache, full page cache(If it exists) sessions, and log folders from with the var directory

Go into core_config_data

Using a Database tool,  search (value "contains" http)

This will show you your site urls referenced from within the database.

Make sure web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

both reference your domain without any https: at first

i.e they both should contain http://mydomain.com/

Last as kaigorodov says above check the cookie_path

[image]

Next,  reference your .htaccess file.  Here's an option

via terminal

cd into the root of your install. i.e

cd /public_html/magento

Again verify your .htaccess file..  One option is duplicate your existing file and rename the .htaccess-sample to .htaccess and use this one to be sure this isn't causing your problem.

Could be web server caching.  Try restarting that if you have ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop problem often related to improper magento cookies configuration. Try to check the `cookie_domain` and `cookie_path` settings in the `core_config_data` table.

Answer (score 0):

It's a www to non-www redirect.  Because I don't have the install in front of me to help I can't narrow down the cause,   but maybe within your core_config_data you use www on some and non www on others. Maybe your .htaccess has a www redirect in place?

Maybe Catalog > URL Rewrite Management  turning the www to non redirect off may fix your problem